# Display all tables from MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code right now:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname"); // connect

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { // checking connection
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
```

So, there are several tables in this database. I want to display all the name of all of the tables. I've been searching for this on the internet for a while, but I couldn't find the right answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The SQL statement you want is:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these queries in your PHP code:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| begueradj          |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
| tester             |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.04 sec)

mysql> use tester;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_tester |
+------------------+
| images           |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```